# NuxtJS 2 AsyncData and axios

Tags: axios, nuxt.js

I'm building a static site using Nuxt JS 2. Specifically, I'm trying to build dynamic pages from a JSON file (/static/js/cro-tales.js). For this, some utilising asyncData.

My JSON file is in the static folder, I've tried a version with axios, which works with `yarn dev` but fails to generate the pages when I build the site. Here's the code for that:

```js
export default {

  async asyncData({params, $axios}){
    const cro_tales = await $axios.$get("/js/cro-tales.json");
    let comic = {}
    for(let i = 0; i<cro_tales.length;i++){
      if ( cro_tales[i]['fields']['Slug'] == params.slug){
        //comics[i]['Genres_list'] = comics[i]['Genres'].split(',');
        comic = cro_tales[i];
        return { comic, cro_tales };
      }
    }
    
  }
}
```

I've also tried a version using fetch instead of axios, and that works but when reloading the page, I get an Invalid URL error. Here's the code for that:

```js
export default {
  async asyncData({ params }) {
    const res = await fetch('/js/cro-tales.json');
    const cro_tales = await res.json();
    let comic = {};
      for (let i = 0; i < cro_tales.length; i++) {
      if (cro_tales[i].fields.Slug === params.slug) {
        comic = cro_tales[i];
        break;
      }
    }
    return { comic, cro_tales };
  }
}
```

So neither of these approaches are working. What should my approach be?

Here's my nuxt.config:

```js
export default {
  // Target: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-target/
  target: 'static',

  // Global page headers: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-head
  head: {
    title: 'iqbala.com',
    meta: [
      { charset: 'utf-8' },
      { name: 'viewport', content: 'width=device-width, initial-scale=1' },
      { hid: 'description', name: 'description', content: '' },
      { name: 'format-detection', content: 'telephone=no' }
    ],
    link: [
      { rel: 'icon', type: 'image/x-icon', href: '/favicon.ico' }
    ]
  },
  
  // Global CSS: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-css
  css: [
    'tachyons/css/tachyons.css',
    '~assets/styles/global'
  ],

  // Plugins to run before rendering page: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-plugins
  plugins: [
  ],

  // Auto import components: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-components
  components: true,

  // Modules for dev and build (recommended): https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  buildModules: [
  ],

  // Modules: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-modules
  modules: [
    // https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
    '@nuxtjs/pwa',
    'nuxt-gsap-module',
    'bootstrap-vue/nuxt',
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxt/content',
    '@nuxtjs/sitemap'
  ],
  axios: {
    //baseURL: 'http://localhost:3000'
  },
  mode: 'universal', // or 'spa' for SPA mode
  ssr: true,
  router:{
    mode: 'history'
  },
  sitemap: {
    hostname: 'https://iqbala.com/',
    routes: [] // all the dynamic routes
  },
  // PWA module configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/pwa
  pwa: {
    manifest: {
      lang: 'en'
    }
  },
  // Build Configuration: https://go.nuxtjs.dev/config-build
  build: {
    extend: function (config, {isDev, isClient}) {
      config.node = {
          fs: "empty"
      };
    },
    //standalone: true,
  }
}
```

Any advice would be awesome! Thanks in advance to anyone who responds to this!

Comment: `My JSON file is in the static folder` - then why not import the data directly instead of fetching?

Comment: I tried that but couldn't find the right code. asyncData didn't seem to pick up the import

Comment: Okay, I just updated to use import and it seems working. But on generate, I get "ERROR Could not resolve routes". After another update, I get 'ReferenceError: fetch is not defined'